# Error in P[i] <- (k[i] - mean(k))^2 : object 'P' not found

Tags: r, for-loop

Please help me with this problem
I would like to have vector `P(2.0408163 2.0408163 6.6122449 2.4693878 0.3265306 0.1836735 2.0408163)` but problem is with `i` in `P[i]`.

```
k<-c(5,5,9,8,7,6,5)
for (i in 1:length(k)) {P[i] <- (k[i] - mean(k))^2}
```

> Error in P[i] <- (k[i] - mean(k))^2 : object 'P' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the error because you're trying to access by index from something you've not defined yet.

Although, **You dont need to iterate for each value in `k`**, if P is derived from `k`, **a better solution is:**

```
P <- (k - mean(k))^2
```